# How to access a specific element while using a List of a List of a primitive data type in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, graph

I have recently started working with graphs using an adjacency matrix, and while a 2D integer array usually suffices for weighted graphs, there is this particular problem such that whenever I access an element of row *m* and column *n*, I have to delete that row and column. As removal is only possible(easily) in lists, I tried to switch to a data structure with a List of Lists but soon realised that I could not have individual access to the elements of a single list. Here is an example to clarify-

```
import java.util.*;
public class List_Of_List_Example
{
    static List list1=new ArrayList<List>();
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
       List lt1=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
       list1.add(lt1);
       List lt2=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
       list1.add(lt2);
       List lt3=Arrays.asList(list1.get(0));
       System.out.println(lt3.get(0));//Outputs [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

In the above code, I want to be able to access each individual element of lt3,after obtaining that speific list from the main list. Any ideas for how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks

P.S This same issue remained even if I tried using a List of integer arrays.

Comment: If you are working with graphs, then I suggest that you use that data structure specifically.  A list is a graph, but a graph isn't necessarily a list.

Comment: Anyway in which I can quickly remove rows and columns then?@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: *Unrelated:* 1) You can't have a "List of a List of a primitive data type in Java". `List` cannot store primitive values. 2) Don't use *raw* generic types. `List` is a big no-no. It should be `List<Integer> lt1` and `List<List<Integer>> list1`. 3) The primitive `int` values `1`, `2`, ... are autoboxed to `Integer` for you by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `Arrays.asList()` when assigning to `lt3`.

Also, don't use *raw* generic types.

Here is your fixed code with generic type arguments specified:

```
static List<List<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> lt1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    list1.add(lt1);
    List<Integer> lt2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
    list1.add(lt2);
    List<Integer> lt3 = list1.get(0); // Same as lt1
    System.out.println(lt3.get(0)); // Outputs 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
List lt3=Arrays.asList(list1.get(0));
```

do

```
List lt3=list1.get(0);
```

But don't overlook the comments. They are more important.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions. :-)

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //departFile();
    ArrayList<Integer> lt1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lt1.add(1);
    lt1.add(2);
    lt1.add(3);
    list1.add(lt1);

    ArrayList<Integer> lt2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lt2.add(4);
    lt2.add(5);
    lt2.add(6);
    list1.add(lt2);

    ArrayList<Integer> lt3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lt3.addAll(list1.get(0));
    list1.add(lt3);

    System.out.println("[1][CHECK ITEMS of lt3]");
    for(int i=0; i<lt3.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("lt3["+i+"] = " + lt3.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("\n[2][CHECK ITEMS of list1]");
    for(int row=0; row<list1.size(); row++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> rowItem = list1.get(row);

        System.out.print("row "+row+" :: ");
        for(int col=0; col<rowItem.size(); col++) {
            System.out.print("[" + rowItem.get(col) + "]");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    System.out.println("\n[3][REMOVE ITEM of list1]");
    list1.get(2).remove(1);     // remove item index 1 of lt3 

    for(int row=0; row<list1.size(); row++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> rowItem = list1.get(row);

        System.out.print("row "+row+" :: ");
        for(int col=0; col<rowItem.size(); col++) {
            System.out.print("[" + rowItem.get(col) + "]");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

**[RESULT]**

```
[1][CHECK ITEMS of lt3]
lt3[0] = 1
lt3[1] = 2
lt3[2] = 3

[2][CHECK ITEMS of list1]
row 0 :: [1][2][3]
row 1 :: [4][5][6]
row 2 :: [1][2][3]

[3][REMOVE ITEM of list1]
row 0 :: [1][2][3]
row 1 :: [4][5][6]
row 2 :: [1][3]
```